# Add Windows Server 2012 DC in existing 2008R2 without updating schema

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012

i have Active Directory infrastructure and all domain contollers running WS 2008 R2 and operate on schema version 47.

It is possible to add WS 2012 domain controller without any changes to domain schema ?

Comment: What concerns do you have about upgrading the schema?

Answer (score 14):

No...it isn't possible.  The schema has to be updated.

Here's the list of what is changed: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj916256.aspx

Answer (score 12):

No it is not possible.  Server 2012 schema version is 56.

You must update your schema before a Server 2012 domain controller is allowed in your forest.

Adprep is now baked into Add-ADDomainController and Server Manager and will run automatically if needed when promoting a Server 2012 DC.

But I still prefer to run adprep myself because I'm used to it.  Copy the adprep folder from \support\adprep on the Server 2012 install media.

Then run `adprep /forestprep`.  That should get you to schema version 56.

Wait for replication throughout the forest.

Then run `adprep /domainprep`.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you're not aware: You DO have to update the schema to support DC's running newer Operating systems, but you DO NOT have to raise the Domain or forest functionality level, meaning you can keep older DC's in situ.

As an example: I have a 2012R2 Domain Controller, running on the 2003 Forest and Domain functionality level: I can have any DC's from 2003 - 2012 R2 on that network: Only 2000 DC's are excluded.